# What is a more professional way of saying, I want to make it up to you?

Tags: euphemisms

A dissatisfied customer is leaving negative reviews. I want to write back and let him know we want to make it up to him, however that doesn't sound very professional.

Comment: If you're in the wrong, apologizing and attempting to address the person's grievances sounds pretty professional to me.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for a *euphemism* [as per tag]? I'd say this would be counterproductive - it'd look like you're trying to avoid responsibility or downplay the issues.

Answer (score 1):

How about "as a gesture of goodwill"?

Alternatively (spinning out a broader context) something as straightforward as:

> We value our customers. The experience you had doesn't reflect our standards, and we're truly sorry. Please accept xyz as a gift. We look forward to abc in the future.

Comment: The problem with  "as a gesture of goodwill" is that it is often used to cover a situation in which the trader does not acknowledge fault but wants to put an end to an irritating correspondence. An actual apology is what the dissatisfied customer wants.